# can we print ascending order without loops

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

usually we use loops to print numbers in ascending order but can we print loops without using loops in c++

I tried doing so without the help of loops with if else but the program became very lengthy and i was not able to build a proper logic for that

Comment: You could try recursion.

Comment: Assuming the amount of iteration is not fixed at compile time, loops are the most natural solution. Without loops you could use recursion in many cases but recursion will have system limitations. You could also use an ugly solution like a goto and a conditional but that in my book is still a loop.

Comment: I would want clarification on whether "without loops" just means no visible loops in OP's file. Would `std::for_each()` satisfy the (odd) requirement? Or a call to `std::copy`?